# How to determine if a dispatch semaphore is being waited on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

How can you determine if a `dispatch_semaphore_t` is being waited on w/out causing a wait on it?  I was initially thinking:

```
if ( dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) ) {
    NSLog(@"No more resources, wait");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Resources available, shouldn't wait");
}
```

But the act of doing `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` the semaphore is decremented so then I was thinking:

```
if ( dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) ) {
    NSLog(@"No more resources, wait");
} else {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(mySemaphore);
    NSLog(@"Resources available, shouldn't wait");
}
```

Which has the end result of not decrementing the semaphore but seems like a hack, suggestions?

**EDIT**

As I was typing out what I'm doing and how I came to this conclusion I realized that I was indeed thinking about the solution the wrong way, I just wanted to know if I was waiting on a resource and be able to show a 'wait' dialog to the user.  I think this is the *correct* way to do it:

```
    [self showWait];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(mySemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self hideWait];
        });
    });
```

Comment: This can't be done (at least not reliably) and the fact that you want to do it suggests a design error. I join @das in asking: what are you trying to do at a high level of abstraction? What situation makes you think you want to know if a semaphore is being waited on?

Comment: @KenThomases You're right, I was coming at this the wrong way, I EDITed in the better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dispatch_semaphore_wait()` has only decremented the semaphore value if it returns 0.

If the timeout expired (i.e. it returns non-zero), the semaphore value has NOT been decremented.

Think of the decrement in the success case as taking ownership of one of the resources managed by the counting semaphore, if you signaled right after a successful wait, you would indicate that you have stopped using that resource right away, which is presumably not what you want.

What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Marking this as the solution as @das's statements are correct AND I was coming at this the wrong way :)

Comment: Why on earth can't the documentation specify this behaviour for `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` - it says absolutely nothing about the semaphore value NOT being decremented if the timeout has expired and the resource is already taken. However, excellent answer - I can confirm this is the case, the semaphore decrement only happens when testing against `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` returns 0. You don't need to `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` in the non-zero case. Thank you!

Comment: @rob-glassey no argument that the documentation is deficient on this point, please file a [bug](http://bugreport.apple.com)!

Comment: Done :) - My semaphores were occasionally getting over-released, in a very inconsistent way and hence weren't doing their job at all. Your answer while answering something slightly different was the only thing I came across that put me on the right track.